# Handling GL_RGBA and GL_ALPHA textures with the same shader?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glsl

So my application uses mostly rgba textures for rendering, but in a few cases I use alpha masks for things like rendering text.

I'd like the output of my fragment shader to be the value of the texture sampler at the given coordinate multiplied by a color uniform I pass in.  The problem is that I can't find a simple solution that handles both cases.

So for rgba textures this gives the desired result:

```
gl_FragColor = texture2D(diffuseTexture, varTexcoord.st, 0.0) * color;
```

But for alpha textures, the output is always black.  I'm assuming the texture sampler treats every pixel of an alpha texture as: rgba(0, 0, 0, alpha), and I want it to be treated as rgba(1, 1, 1, alpha).  I can get the desired result on alpha textures with this:

```
gl_FragColor = texture2D(diffuseTexture, varTexcoord.st, 0.0).w * color;
```

But obviously this breaks the rgba textures.

I'm fairly new to GLSL, and I'm wondering if there's a good way to handle both cases, or if I'm going to have to have 2 different shaders, or else convert all my aplha textures to rgba.

**edit:**

I think I'm going to end up re-packing my alpha textures as GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA textures when loading assets.

Comment: Your assumption is correct, GL_ALPHA maps to RGBA as { R=0, G=0, B=0, A=A }

Comment: Are you using desktop OpenGL or OpenGL ES?

Comment: .w is semantically incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different ways to process data. So you have two different shaders. Switch them. Shaders reflect what is to happen.

If you use the old, depreceated fixed function pipeline for each setting of glTexEnv, lighting, etc. a specific shader is created in situ.

Switching shaders is as simple as calling glUseProgramm

Comment: Really, it's one way to process data. The data is functionally the same; the only difference is that some of the data is not quite formatted correctly. That's why *desktop* OpenGL has [texture swizzling](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture#Swizzle_mask), so you can take care of minor formatting issues like this without involving shaders.

Comment: @NicolBolas: In that simple case yes, but what if there are two shaders that process channels in very different ways.

Comment: Then he wouldn't be asking for a single-shader solution. His *specific* problem is that he wants a single-shader solution because the shader code is identical. The only problem with the math is the RGB components coming from the alpha texture. He's not looking for a general solution to stuff shader code into a texture fetch or something; he's looking for a solution to this specific case of getting 0's instead of 1's. Swizzle masks exist to solve this exact problem, which can happen more often than you might think.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Oh, I know they're plenty. I'm using swizzle mask in a lot of programs myself. However I often observe people making assumptions about their problem, forcing themself into a rather strange mental model, while the easier *and* better solution is right in front of them. Remember that a swizzle mask may be implemented by the OpenGL implementation by in-situ shader recompilation. So applying a swizzle mask may have the same impact on performance as switching shaders.

Comment: "*So applying a swizzle mask may have the same impact on performance as switching shaders.*" Unlikely. The user changing program state also means changing *uniform* state stored in the program, because you're switching programs. The driver modifying a shader doesn't have to do that. It can just upload a slightly different set of shader data, and that's it. So even if it does do in-situ modification, it doesn't need to do what the user would have to do to get the job done.